# Match doesn't found shortest paths

Tags: c#, neo4j

I have task. I have array of point. I know time, which need spent to go from one point to second. For me reccomended use neo4j to search shortest path .
First I create in c# point(s):

```
public bool AddPoint(Point point)
{
    bool sucess = false;
    try
    {
        client.Cypher
            .Create("(point:Point {newPoint})")
            .WithParam("newPoint", point)
            .ExecuteWithoutResults();

        sucess = true;
        Console.WriteLine("The point was added!");
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error! " + exception);
    }
    return sucess;
}
```

Second function link two points:

```
public void LinkTwoPoint(string firstName, string secondName, string time)
        {
            try
            {
                client.Cypher
                .Match("(point1:Point)", "(point2:Point)")
                .Where((Point point1) => point1.Name == firstName)
                .AndWhere((Point point2) => point2.Name == secondName)
                .Create(string.Format("point1-[r:Time{0}time:{1}{2}]->point2","{", time,"}"))
                .ExecuteWithoutResults();

                Console.WriteLine("Ok. Point was connected!");
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error! " + exception);
            }
        }
```

But when I try search shortest path (query in browser. This is not c# code), the system doesn't found anything:

```
MATCH (pointStart:Point { name:"Point_B" }),(pointEnd:Point { name:"Point_E" }),
  p = allShortestPaths((pointStart)-[*]-(pointEnd))
RETURN p
```

Can you suggest anything to fix it?

P.S. After execute this query:

```
MATCH (pointStart:Point { name:"Point_B" })-[r]-(pointEnd:Point { name:"Point_E" })
RETURN pointStart, pointEnd, r
```

No rows was founded.

[image]

Comment: Is that C# in the last code?

Comment: no. This is query, which I call in UI of Neo4j. In my case: http://localhost:7474/browser/

Comment: There is no "RETURN" keyword in C# tho. You might want to format it a little so that is is indeed C#

Comment: Sorry, I made mistake in previous message. This is not c# code.

Comment: It looks like your property key is `Name` in the code but then you're using `name` in Cypher. Property keys are case sensitive.

Answer (score 1):

First, try following query

```
MATCH (pointStart:Point { name:"Point_B" })-[r]-(pointEnd:Point { name:"Point_E" })
RETURN pointStart, pointEnd, r
```